# Antonym of additive - Subtractive?

Tags: antonyms

We have the word *additive* as in "An additive process" or "additive manufacturing".

### Why do we not have the antonym *subtractive*?

This seems relevant to styles of `coding`. Especially in css.

When building for mobile first, the process of making it desktop compatible is **additive**. Adding or including assets as the page expands. While building desktop first, the process of making it mobile compatibile would be **subtractive**. Removing or hiding elements or assets as the page collapses.

It could also be used when talking about SVGs or other image manipulation tools when subtracting a layer mask. "Additive blending" is [used](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blend_modes#Dodge_and_burn) to describe "Linear Dodge". Additive gradients are also discussed.

Comment: We [do](https://www.nebraskamanufacturing.com/2016/02/making-subtractive-manufacturing-matter-again/). Granted, it’s not a common term, but then, neither is *additive manufacturing*.

Comment: Oh you're right. I checked oxford just now and its defined. merriam-webster.com and dictionary.com didn't have it.

Comment: Good find! Feel free to post your own answer for the benefit of others who have the same question. Cite and link to the dictionary, and use my link (or others) as an example of the term used ‘in the wild’. This helps establish that the term can be understood in the sense you intend. Use the answer box below if you’re posting an answer. (Posting an answer to your own question in this context is encouraged.)

Comment: Thanks @Lawrence I added the answer. Foolish of me not to thoroughly check dictionaries first.

Answer (score 1):

So it is a word. Just uncommonly used and not always defined in some online thesauruses [merriam-webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/subtractive) or [thesaurus](http://www.thesaurus.com/misspelling?term=subtractive&s=t).

It is defined in the [dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/subtractive)

It's use in the wild as pointed out in the comments [Making Subtractive Manufacturing Matter Again](https://www.nebraskamanufacturing.com/2016/02/making-subtractive-manufacturing-matter-again/)